# How to subscribe Asp.net website to external Java webservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

We are looking for solution to broadcast data from a Java webservice to a Asp.NET website (with MVC4 and .Net 4.5). This ASP.NET website then broad cast received data to all of its client browsers (SignalR seems quite capable to handle the later part). 
People from Jabbr chat (SignalR Chat forum) suggested to have a controller method in my web site to accept post request and let Java webservice call this method with data to publish.

Please suggest if this is the best approach or if there are other ways by which asp.net website can subscribe to Java web service.

P.S. Both Asp.Net and Java webservice are maintained by internal teams.

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time updates (as suggested by the use of SignalR) it only makes sense that the .NET app should expose a web service which the Java app should call to notify that even has occured. The other option is polling periodically but then you lose the real time notification.